# Why different COPY paths between docker build and docker-compose builds?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm new to the Docker universe and am trying to figure out how to do things. I'm relying heavily on the book [Docker In
Action](https://www.manning.com/books/docker-in-action-second-edition). I've modified the Makefile in Chapter 10
to build my multistage images. Here's a sample:

```
.PHONY: image-base
image-base: metadata
  @echo "Building Base Image"
  docker image build --tag src:$(BUILD_ID)-base \
  -f src/Dockerfile \
  --target baseImage \
  --build-arg BUILD_ID='$(BUILD_ID)' \
  --build-arg BUILD_DATE='$(BUILD_TIME_RFC_3339)' \
  --build-arg VCS_REF='$(VCS_REF)' \
  .
  @echo "Built Base Image. BUILD_ID: $(BUILD_ID)"

## image-prod   : Build the prod image
.PHONY: image-prod
image-prod: metadata image-base
  @echo "Building Prod Image"
  docker image build --tag src:$(BUILD_ID)-prod \
  -f src/Dockerfile \
  --target prodImage \
  --build-arg BUILD_ID='$(BUILD_ID)' \
  --build-arg BUILD_DATE='$(BUILD_TIME_RFC_3339)' \
  --build-arg VCS_REF='$(VCS_REF)' \
  .
  @echo "Built Prod Image. BUILD_ID: $(BUILD_ID)"
```

My dir structure looks like this:

```
.
├── BUILD.md
├── Makefile
├── docker-compose.yml
├── docker-dev.yml
├── docker-prod.yml
├── docker-staging.yml
├── docker-testing.yml
├── src
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── composer.json
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── <elided>
│   ├── php-apache
│   │   ├── 000-default.conf
│   │   ├── php.ini
│   │   └── <elided>
├── <elided>
```

Here's a sample of my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  php-apache:
    image: 'src:latest'
    build:
      context: ./src
      dockerfile: ./src/Dockerfile
    container_name: foo-app
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    env_file:
      - ./src/.env.dev
```

To build my images I do:

```
make image-base
export BUILD_ID=20200902-204128-c2aa451
make image-prod
```

To bring up my containers, I run

```
make up env=prod
```

where

```
## up env=<env>   : Bring up environments. env values are base, prod, dev, staging. (Not working)
.PHONY: up
up:
  docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-$(env).yml up -d
```

To get the images to build with `docker`, I configure my src/Dockerfile thusly:

```
COPY ./src/php-apache/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/custom.ini
COPY ./src/composer.json /var/www/html/composer.json
```

But, to get `docker-compose` to run things, I need the src/Dockerfile to look like this:

```
COPY ./php-apache/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/custom.ini
COPY ./composer.json /var/www/html/composer.json
```

Note the missing `/src` path.

Yes, I've changed the docker-compose.yml file to read:

```
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
```

And it didn't help.

What do I need to do to get  the same environment(?) to build images with docker and build/run containers with docker-compose?

Answer (score 1):

You're changing the context between the two builds. The COPY command will copy files from the context into the image.

In this command:

```
docker image build --tag src:$(BUILD_ID)-base \
  -f src/Dockerfile \
  --target baseImage \
  --build-arg BUILD_ID='$(BUILD_ID)' \
  --build-arg BUILD_DATE='$(BUILD_TIME_RFC_3339)' \
  --build-arg VCS_REF='$(VCS_REF)' \
  .
```

The context is the last arg, `.`, or the current directory. While in the compose file:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  php-apache:
    image: 'src:latest'
    build:
      context: ./src
      dockerfile: ./src/Dockerfile
```

the context is `./src`. And when you change to:

```
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
```

that would require the compose file to be moved into the same directory as the Dockerfile.

To replicate your `docker build` command, the compose file would be:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  php-apache:
    image: 'src:latest'
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./src/Dockerfile
```

---

I've reproduce this working in my own lab with:

```
$ tree .
.
├── docker-compose.yml
└── src
    ├── Dockerfile
    └── test.txt

$ cat docker-compose.yml 
version: '3.8'
services:
  test:
    image: test-63729350:latest
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/Dockerfile

$ cat src/Dockerfile 
FROM busybox
COPY src/test.txt .

$ docker-compose build
Building test
Step 1/2 : FROM busybox
 ---> c7c37e472d31
Step 2/2 : COPY src/test.txt .
 ---> 33dc5a1ac7a1

Successfully built 33dc5a1ac7a1
Successfully tagged test-63729350:latest

$ docker run -it --rm test-63729350:latest ls -al
total 48
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Sep  3 18:51 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Sep  3 18:51 ..
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root             0 Sep  3 18:51 .dockerenv
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root         12288 Jun 27 00:21 bin
drwxr-xr-x    5 root     root           360 Sep  3 18:51 dev
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Sep  3 18:51 etc
drwxr-xr-x    2 nobody   nogroup       4096 Jun 27 00:21 home
dr-xr-xr-x  412 root     root             0 Sep  3 18:51 proc
drwx------    2 root     root          4096 Jun 27 00:21 root
dr-xr-xr-x   13 root     root             0 Sep  3 18:51 sys
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            10 Sep  3 18:44 test.txt
drwxrwxrwt    2 root     root          4096 Jun 27 00:21 tmp
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 Jun 27 00:21 usr
drwxr-xr-x    4 root     root          4096 Jun 27 00:21 var
```

Comment: Makes sense, but when I make that change, I get `ERROR: Cannot locate specified Dockerfile: ./src/Dockerfile`.

Comment: Is the compose file still in the parent folder? And is the Dockerfile still in src? And you're running the build from the parent folder?

Comment: Yes to each question.

Comment: @faberfedor I'm not able to reproduce your error, see the [mcve] above.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @BMitch for pointing me in the right(?) direction.

I made the following changes:

- docker build context changed from `.` to `./src`.
- docker compose `context` changed from `./src` to `.` and `dockerfile` changed from `./src/Dockerfile` to `./Dockerfile`.
- removed the `src/` from the Dockerfile COPY commands.

And now it builds! I hope that's the right way to do it.

(TBH, I'm not sure it's building The Right Thing, but it's building!)

Comment: Note that the context of `.` and dockerfile of `./Dockerfile` are the defaults. If you're not changing the defaults, you can completely remove the lines from the compose file.